# Displaying Images in Tumb Nails format in JSP

Tags: jsp

In my JSP Page , i am displying a single Image as shown .

```
<img src="http://your_host/servlet/BannerServlet?config_file"  width=125 height=125>
```

This works fine when i display a Single Image , but what if i want to display a number of images (Like ThumbNails of Images displayed in porno sites )

Please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display several images, you need to have several `<img/>` tags, each with a different `src` attribute.

It's not a good idea to use the real image just to display its thumbnail (using smaller width and height attributes), because it wastes bandwidth and takes more time: it forces the browser to download a big image (hundreds of KBs) instead of a small one (some KBs). So reduce your images and store two copies on the server: the thumbnail and the actual image.